# model.save receives Not JSON Serializable error. tensorflow1.14.0

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

i tried to implement a simple architecture

```
def conv_block_A(layer):
    block = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(layer)
    block = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=196, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(block)
    block = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')(block)
    block = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(block)
    block = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(block)

    return block

def PoolingAndDense(input):
    dense = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format='channels_last')(input)
    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64)(dense)
    dense = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(dense)
    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32)(dense)
    dense = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(dense)
    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)(dense)
    dense = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(dense)
    return dense


input_shape = input_shape
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape,dtype="float32")
stem = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same')(input_layer)
first_conv_block_output = conv_block_A(stem)
mtss = PoolingAndDense(first_conv_block_output)
Model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=mtss)
```

but model.save doesn't work for tensorflow 1.14 but works for 1.15 how do i make it work for 1.14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after going through [tensorflow documentations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf) for each and every line in my code, i changed

```
dense = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(dense)
```

to

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(dense)
```